# NodeJS callback scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As a js/node newcomer, I'm having some problems understanding how I can get around this issue.

Basically I have a list of objects that I would like to save to a MongoDB database if they don't already exist.

Here is some code:

```
var getDataHandler = function (err, resp, body) {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var item = data[i];
        models.Entry.findOne({id: item.id}, function(err, res) {
            if (err) { }
            else if (result === null) {
                var entry = new models.Entry(item);
                feedbackEntry.save(function(err, result) { 
                    if (err) {}
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that because it is asynchronous, once the `new models.Entry(item)` line is executed the value of item will be equal to the last element in the data array for every single callback.

What kind of pattern can I use to avoid this issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two kinds of patterns are available :

**1)** Callbacks. That is you go on calling functions from your functions by passing them as parameters. Callbacks are generally fine but, especially server side when dealing with database or other asynchronous resources, you fast end in "callback hell" and you may grow tired of looking for tricks to reduce the indentation levels of your code. And you may sometimes wonder how you *really* deal with exceptions. But callbacks are the basis : you *must* understand how to deal with that problem using callbacks.

**2)** [Promises](http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/). Using promises you may have something like that (example from my [related blog post](http://canop.org/blog/?p=516)) :

```
db.on(userId)          // get a connection from the pool
.then(db.getUser)      // use it to issue an asynchronous query
.then(function(user){  // then, with the result of the query
    ui.showUser(user); // do something
}).finally(db.off);    // and return the connection to the pool
```

Instead of passing the next function as callback, you just chain with `then` (in fact it's a little more complex, you have other functions, for example to deal with collections and parallel resolution or error catching in a clean way).

---

Regarding your scope problem with the variable evolving before the callback is called, the standard solution is this one :

```
for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
   (function(i){
      // any function defined here (a callback) will use the value of i fixed when iterating
   })(i);
});
```

This works because calling a function creates a scope and the callback you create in that scope retains a pointer to that scope where it will fetch `i` (that's called a closure).

Comment: Thanks! You mentioned callbacks - i'm passing functions as arguments currently, but how could I use the callback pattern in this way whilst ensuring the item variable is not always the last element in the list ? Also, with promises will the current item be referenced, or the value of item when the promise is returned ?

Comment: I edited regarding the "item variable is not always the last element in the list" point.

Comment: With promises, you'd deal with collections and use the `map` function. It might be a little hard to read but [here's an example](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/main.js#L317).